# Best way to convert array into string with PHP keeping Keys and Values

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array:

```
[
  "Cuzco" => "Peru"
  "Lima" => "Peru"
]
```

I need the output to be: `Cuzco (Peru) + Lima (Peru)`

Can I use `http_build_query` for this? I tried

```
http_build_query($array, " + ")
```

Comment: `http_build_query` will create `Cuzco=Peru + Lima=Peru`.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it in a more specific format, with parenthesis and no equals sign.

Comment: I know, that's why `http_build_query` won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the `key (value)` strings in an array, then call `implode()` to combine them.

```
$a = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $a[] = "$key ($value)";
}
$result = implode(' + ', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

string concatenation using array_walk for all elements of the array.

```
array_walk($array,function($v,$k) use(&$result){
  $result .= ($result? " + ":"")."$k ($v)";
});
```